# How to specify a state file name in terraform backend?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I created a terraform `gcs` backend using the block :

```
 terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket                      = "<redacted_bucket_name>"
    prefix                      = "base/terraform.state"
    impersonate_service_account = "<redacted_service_account>@<redacted_project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

By performing a `terraform init`, this creates the state file in the specified bucket but in a directory :

```
<bucket>
|--base (Directory)
  |--terraform.state (Directory)
    |--default.state (File)
```

How do I specify the name of the state file?
I know I've used the `prefix` wrong in this example, but there is nothing in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is the name of the Terraform [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) that you're working in (hence `default`).

You use workspaces to separate your deployments when you're using the same code for multiple environments.

For example, if you were to perform a `terraform init` with a backend configured, it would use the `default` workspace and create a `default.tfstate` within the bucket.

If you were to do a `terraform workspace new prod` and performed a `terraform init` you would be working against a state file of `prod.tfstate`.

You don't have to use workspaces though as they can add complexity to the pipeline. You could just as easily have a different backend or place the state file under a different prefix; you can think of prefix in regards to GCS backends as a directory structure to place the state file.

e.g. `prefix=terraform/myproject/nonprod` would keep a `default.tfstate` under a nonprod directory so it's separate from the other environments. Whatever works for you.

> prefix - (Optional) GCS prefix inside the bucket. Named states for workspaces are stored in an object called /.tfstate.

[source](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/gcs#prefix)